# Bukkit Right-Clicking Stone does not return anything

Tags: java, bukkit

How do you detect if someone has right-clicked block (For example, stone) in Bukkit? I have tried many suggestions but none of them return anything.

`Main.java`

```
package me.ben.test;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Click(), this);
        getLogger().info("The Plugin Has Been Enabled!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getLogger().info("The Plugin Has Been Disabled!");
    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label,
            String[] args) {

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("hello") && sender instanceof Player) {

            Player player = (Player) sender;

            player.sendMessage("Hello, " + player.getName() + "!");

            return true;
        } else if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("isonline")
                && args.length == 1) {

            Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
            if (target == null) {

                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Player " + args[0]
                        + " is not online.");

                return true;

            } else if (target != null) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Player " + args[0]
                        + " is online.");

                return true;
            } else return false;

        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

`Click.java`

```
package me.ben.test;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockPlaceEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Click extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
    @EventHandler 
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
        event.getPlayer().sendMessage("Heyyyyyyy");
    }
}
```

I have tried other ones but this one was the last one I tried and It seems the simplest.

I added the line into the `onEnable` section.

Comment: Could you provide the code that you've tried?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an [`Event`](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Event_API_Reference) and check when the player interacts:

```
@EventHandler //you NEED to have @EventHandler before any event
public void playerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e){
  //this will be called automatically by bukkit whenever a player interacts
  if(e.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK)){
    //the player right-clicked a block
    Material m = e.getClickedBlock().getType(); //get the block type clicked
    if(m.equals(Material.STONE){
      //the block clicked was stone.
    }
  }
}
```

Then you need to make sure that the class this is in `implements Listener`:

```
public class MyListenerClass implements Listener{
  //events & other methods
}
```

and then you need to register events in the `onEnable()` method of your Main class (the one that `extends JavaPlugin`)

```
public class MyMainClass extends JavaPlugin{
  @Override
  public void onEnable(){
    //enabled
    this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new MyListenerClass(), this));
  }
}
```

Comment: that did not work. I added both of my classes. (I realize there is some dead code)

Comment: Thank you for giving me so much detail on why it does't work. Let me put on my physic hat and read what you mean :P... Does the class that has the event `implement Listener`? Do you register events in your `onEnable()` method: `this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new MyListenerClass(), this));`? Do you have `@EventHandler` before the event? Does the Event method only have one argument, `PlayerInteractEvent`? Could you provide me with the code that you're trying to use?

Comment: I am so sorry for my lack of detail.

Comment: Sorry to revive but could your problem be that both your classes (click and main)  extend JavaPlugin, although you should always only have one class extending JavaPlugin? Delete extends JavaPlugin from your click class.